# genymotion virtual device doesn't work properly in ubuntu

Tags: android, emulation, virtualbox, genymotion

i have recently installed `genymotion` 2.3.0 on `ubuntu 14.04lts` and created a virtual device but when i lunch the virtual device it doesn't show the android home screen in it's right place and i don't have any control on the virtual device . here is a screen shot what i am facing with:

[image]

i don't get any errors but after a few seconds virtual device suddenly closes up !! i don't know where the problem is! i have tried to reinstall `genymotion` and recreate virtual device with no luck !
so any help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have finally solved my problem by installing "`NVidia` legacy binary driver" .

```
System settings > Software & updates > Additional Drivers
```

Comment: This worked for me as long as after choosing that setting I reboot my computer, and then run VirtualBox from the command line and delete all the VM's it shows me, then click the Genymotion plugin icon in Android Studio to launch Genymotion, and make new VM's.

Answer (score 1):

try download some lower 2.3 samsung device or 4.0  version emulator and then run. It seem some hardware is not matches in your pc.

Comment: welcome, I used to work in Ubuntu with geny-motion with emulator 4.0 or 4.3 something and it works with great performance, Now I switch to windows still having genymotion and it work great testing and development (I3, 4GB ram).